# Call static method from the same class

Tags: apex

What is the equivalent of `this` when calling a static method in Apex, besides the class name?

For instance

```
class A {
    public static void foo(){
        this.bar(); //what to use here, instead of this.bar() or A.bar()
    }

    private static void bar(){
        //some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work in static methods

Comment: I know, hence the question....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would simply omit the 'this' and call it as follows:

```
bar();
```

Comment: no problem...sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees :)

Comment: Was not intuitive. Thank you.